# iOs emojis show as Unicode characters in push notification using java

Tags: java, ios, unicode, apple-push-notifications

In apple push notification I am sending emojis in payload and they as showing as Unicode characters in notification.

Using `ApnsPayloadBuilder` to create payload and sending message like

```
payloadBuilder.setAlertBody(new String(msg, "UTF-8"));
```

I am getting this message from our database and emojis are storing like

```
nice \u270c\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4d
```

in db.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? Even for me the unicode is not converting into emoji

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the unicode character in the payload, not as an emoji. So for the winking face in your payload, sent it as \ue405  not as . You can use this website for finding the unicode translations for the emojis http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun

Comment: thanks for the answer but it does not work i pass it as \ue405 in payload but it is not changing to emoji in phone. Is there any other thing that i am missing?

Comment: hm could you add exactly what the payload contains now? using /ue405 directly in an NSString should automatically convert it to the emoji. In your example above the "nice \u270c\ufe0f\ud83d\udc4d" string would not compile because only the first one /u270c is an emoji the others are not recognized, which could also be a source of your issues. Check your emoji unicode's against the link I posted in my answer

Comment: Hi {"alert":"alex left a commented on Ray LaMontagne - Trouble: \"good\" \/u270c","badge":1} this is my payload that sent in push. As you said i only pass  /u270c but it still fails. Unable to under stand the issue.

Comment: When I try to use that string in iOS I get the error "Unknown escaped sequence \/". You do not need this first \ just put the emoji in as /u270c